# How can I tell what is my vaults current storage capacity for stimpaks and radaways?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I know that there's a storage limit for stimpaks and radaways that depend on the number of medbays and science labs I have and how much I upgraded them, but I cannot tell how much is my vault's current limit.

**How can I tell what is my vaults current storage capacity for stimpaks and radaways?**

It's kind of a silly question, but I searched the Net but couldn't find any resource that would answer my question.

Comment: When the number is outlined in red, you have the maximum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate it manually, by clicking the upgrade button on all your medbays and science labs and adding up all the values for storage (plus the 5 base capacity your vault starts with) or you can look at the storage screen. If you are at capacity (or over capacity, from lunchboxes) the number and icon for stimpaks or radaways will have a red outline. If you are under capacity, it will be a green outline.

The first time you collect stimpaks or radaways and you reach capacity, the game will show a graphic of the pip boy struggling to carry a huge load of boxes.

Comment: Also if your total in stock has a red border, then you are at (or above) max storage. If you get Radaway/Stimpaks from a lunchbox, you get to keep them even if it puts you over your max.

Answer (score 2):

You have to manually count this up as there is no global display for the cap of these.

Each room that can make the items tells you how much it can store as well. For example I have a fully upgraded 3wide room producing RadAWay. I get 12 every time and I can store 35... Since I do not have much use for RadAWay that is my personal cap.

EDIT: I have noticed over the last week or so they now have a way of telling you when you are at the cap.. Not what it is, but when you are there. Go to your storage screen and look at the Simpak and Rad-A-Ways on the top right. When they are surrounded by a red outline you are at your cap.

Answer (score 1):

There is no place where you will find that information like in the weapons and outfits area: (Storage space 100/105 for instance).

If I'm not mistaken, each medbay or science lab can hold 10 items. So, 10x(the number of rooms you built for that structure).